# Is there a way to declare a specific module name for a generated .d.ts file (in a javascript project)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsconfig, .d.ts

Is there a way to declare a different module name for a generated `.d.ts` file?

tsc generates `declare module "index" {` instead of `declare module "@myorg/my-pkg"` (which would match the `name` attribute in `package.json`).

Note: This is in a pure javascript project where I'm attempting to generate types.

```js
/* Generated with tsc --init via TypeScript 3.7.0-beta */
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
     "allowJs": true,                         /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
     "declaration": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    "outFile": "./lib/index.js",              /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,              /* Only emit .d.ts files. */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  },
  "include": [
    "js/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately types cannot be outputted to a single file out of the box. There is [an open proposal to add "type bundling" (#4433)](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4433) to add the feature. There are also 3rd party libraries for helping with this.

One other solution, if you're ok with multiple files being output is by specifying `outDir` instead of `outFile`. This was the solution I chose, setting `"outDir": "./types"` in `tsconfig.json` and setting `"types": "./types/index.d.ts"` in `package.json`. This worked as I expected when importing the module to other projects.

Comment: This answer is a few years old. Any changes in this? I'm struggling with the same issue as the OP. My types are being generated but I need a module with the same name as the npm package

Comment: @CraigHarshbarger : Yes, it appears that the same issue is occurring and can be worked around in the same way (with `outDir`).